# mySQL select a column by MONTH

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have a column in my table that stores a date in the format:

2011-08-06 11:00:00

Is there a way to write an sql statement that selects row entries based on this column's MONTH?

Say for example, how would I select all entries in this table where `COLUMN_NAME = "August"`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [MONTH()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month) function.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE MONTH(COL_NAME) = 8
```

If you absolutely need it as a name, you can  use [MONTHNAME()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_monthname) the same way. But the returned name depends on the locale.

Answer (score 1):

To select based on the month's name, use:

```
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(COLUMN_NAME, '%M') = 'August'
```

To do it by month number, use

```
WHERE MONTH(COLUMN_NAME) = 8
```

Answer (score 0):

You could say:

```
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(COLUMN_NAME, "%M") = "August"
```

Helpful page: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format